How to debug Angular Jest tests in VS Code
I've some unit tests set up for my Angular project with Jest.
I've followed some guide, which implied installing jest-preset-angular and then in my angular.json, modify the test part:
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
      "options": {
        "codeCoverageExclude": ["**/*.module.ts"],
        "main": ["setup-jest.ts"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "polyfills": ["src/polyfills.ts"]
      }
    },

Then in the setup-jest.ts,  I mostly have imports:
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

let consoleSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
beforeAll(() => {
  consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'error').mockImplementation(message => {
    if (!message?.message?.includes('Could not parse CSS stylesheet')) {
      global.console.warn(message);
    }
  });
});

afterAll(() => consoleSpy.mockRestore());

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  teardown: { destroyAfterEach: true },
});

This works perfectly when running ng test.
In some cases, I would like to be able to debug a unit test to better understand why it doesn't work and check the values of each variables in a more efficient way than console.log.
I've tried two approaches:

Setting up a VS Code profile to debug
Using the Jest or Jest Runner extensions

But I'm facing the same issue for both cases: they don't execute my setup-jest.ts, and I don't see a way to request this script to be executed before running, and therefore, I receive errors about zone-testing.js not being included:
zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
        Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing

I guess there has to be a way, but I can't find any in the different approaches.


Open your package.json.

Go to the scripts object.

If you are on VSCode, you will see a suggestion for 'Debug', then select your testing script, like npm run test.




After this you will have a VS code debugger connected to your testing setup and you will be able to place breakpoints in VS Code and check any testing code you wish.


You can also try adding the configuration for testing in launch.json.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "command": "npm test",
            "name": "Run npm test",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node-terminal"
        }
    ]
}


Hi Naren! That is a nice working workaround, but this doesn't seems very user friendly, as it forces me to leave the file, make changes, run all the tests(~15min), then make a change. I was hopping to have some way to configure Jest/Jest Runner, or a commandline that could receive my test in parameters?

@J4N updated my answer, with the configuration for vscode debugger in  launch.json

@J4N Have you tried addding focus to the test you're trying to debug, focused with fdescribe /  fit?
This will only run the desired tests and will skip any other tests that aren't focused with the f prefix, then you won't have to run all tests and skip the 15min run time...
Ref:
https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.2/global.html#fdescribe
https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.2/global.html#fit

@JoãoVitorRomerodaCruz Yes I did, but with fdescribe/fit, but while this worked with jasmine, this seems only execute the fit test of the file, but it still execute all the other tests of the other files, which is pretty useless for me.

@J4N Does my updated  answer help, you can debug specific npm command using this
